# Insert date into Access database gives syntax error

Tags: asp.net, date, ms-access

Trying to insert the current date into my Access database throws a syntax error for the INSERT INTO statement.

My database contains a field named Day which has the data type Date/Time.

My insert statement is:

```
Try
    dbConnection.Open()
    sqlString = "INSERT INTO table1 (Day) VALUES (@Day)"
    dbCommand.CommandText = sqlString
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", FormatDateTime(Now, 2))
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Finally
    dbConnection.Close()
End Try
```

When I do `Response.Write(FormatDateTime(Now, 2))` it displays 10/29/2013, which should be an acceptable record.

Doing these also throw a syntax error in the INSERT INTO statement:

```
Try
    dbConnection.Open()
    sqlString = "INSERT INTO table1 (Day) VALUES (Now())"
    dbCommand.CommandText = sqlString
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Finally
    dbConnection.Close()
End Try

Try
    dbConnection.Open()
    sqlString = "INSERT INTO table1 (Day) VALUES (#" & FormatDateTime(Now, 2) & "#)"
    dbCommand.CommandText = sqlString
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Finally
    dbConnection.Close()
End Try
```

Are the dates not in an acceptable format for the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Day](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) is a reserved word.  Enclose that name in square brackets to avoid confusing the db engine.

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO table1 ([Day]) VALUES (Now())"
```

Comment: I wasn't aware Day was a reserved keyword as well. Thank you Hans for providing the link and answering my question!

Comment: Both `Date` and `Day` are functions.  I included a link to Allen Browne's page about reserved and other problem names.  That page also include a link to a free utility you can download and use to examine your Access databases for problem names.

Comment: Hmmm.  I was certain I was replying to a different comment.  :-)  Cheers.